# How can I use '>' to redirect output within Node.js?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

For example suppose I wish to replicate the simple command

```
echo testing > temp.txt
```

This is what I have tried

```
var util  = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var cat = spawn('echo', ['> temp.txt']);
cat.stdin.write("testing");
cat.stdin.end();
```

Unfortunately no success

Comment: Have you tried setting [stdoutStream](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.7.7/lib/child_process.js#L449) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass in the redirection character (>) as an argument to spawn, since it's not a valid argument to the command.
You can either use `exec` instead of spawn, which executes whatever command string you give it in a separate shell, or take this approach:

```
var cat = spawn('echo', ['testing']);

cat.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    fs.writeFile('temp.txt', data, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either pipe node console output a la "node foo.js > output.txt" or you can use the fs package to do file writing

Comment: I think the op wants to run a commandline program and pipe into stdin.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` doesn't seem to block for stdin:

```
~$ echo "hello" | echo
~$
```

^ no output there...

So what you could try is this:

```
var cat = spawn('tee', ['temp.txt']);
cat.stdin.write("testing");
cat.stdin.end();
```

I don't know if that would be useful to you though.

Comment: This is not writing any files when I try

Comment: Ok, sorry, I've updated my answer. It is not the '>' operator though that does the output to file now.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `exec`.

```
const { exec } = require( "child_process" );

exec( "echo > temp.txt" );
```

Not sure what the pros/cons are between `exec` and `spawn`, but it does allow you to easily run the full command and write it or append it to a file.